# How to convert a DataGridViewCell to a Control

Tags: c#, datagridview, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a DataGridView cell to a control:

```
Control dat = new Control();
dat = Convert.ChangeType(dataGridView1[colIndex,rowIndex], typeof(Control));
```

I am fetching the values of colIndex and rowIndes from a index code. The problem is even though I tried many codes to convert, it does not work.

The exception I am getting is:

> Can not implicitly convert an object to a control. An explicit convertion exist(are u missing a cast?)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to convert the cell to a control? A little context might help to give you an answer to your actual problem (since what you are asking to do is generally not possible beyond the EditingControl property).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the control that is hosted by a `DataGridViewCell` you use the [`EditingControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrol.aspx) property of the cell **when the cell is in editing mode**.

This property returns a `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

You can also get at the control within the `DataGridViewEditingControlShowing` event - the `Control` property of `DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs` is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    Control c = e.Control;
}
```

If you want to access the control at other times then (I believe) you are out of luck - I say that based mainly on this quote from the MSDN docs on [`DataGridViewEditingControlShowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx):

> The DataGridView control hosts one editing control at a time, and
>   reuses the editing control whenever the cell type does not change
>   between edits.

Comment: Thanks all for ur replies... i am trying to check the error in datagrid entry and display a bubble message at the position of the error cell in datagrid that is why i am trying to convert the cell to control... from the above answer u ppl have given it shows it is not possible.. is it right... i think i have to use a message box then a buuble message.. any how thanks to all

Comment: @vince - have you looked at the datagridview error text property? This is the out of the box feature designed to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: i used ur idea and the above code.. to get what i was asking for... but it can not be done for checking correct data entered in textbox.. any how but i can show bubble message at that particular cell when incorrect value is being entered....thanks

Comment: @vince do you mean checking the data entered into a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cell as it is typed?

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ChangeType` won't work unless there is a conversion defined between an Object and a Control, which of course there isn't. ChangeType is used most often for primitive types like integers and floats.

If dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex] is a Control, you should be able to use ordinary explicit casting: `dat = (Control) dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex]`

Answer (score 1):

The [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158656.aspx) property of a DataGridView (this is what you access using row and column indexes) is of type [DataGridViewCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx), which is not inherited from [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx).

Comment: Reference to the DataGridViewCell class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx