# C# - Can convert any cell of DataGridView to Control type?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to convert a DataGridViewCell to a Control, but has an error

```
Control ctrl = dgvModeCreate[colIdx, rowIdx] as Control;
```

I don't use EditingControlShowing event.

Can convert any cell datagridview to Control type? It is possible?

**UPDATE ----------------------------------**

If it is not possible, i use EditingControlShowing event, i can get the current cell's Control.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl ctrlCurrentCell = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
```

Is there a way to get Control of the cell in front of the current cell?

Please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: It does not inherit from `Control`, so no.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the question. It is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a DataGridViewCell to a Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214324/how-to-convert-a-datagridviewcell-to-a-control)

Comment: The control that I want to get is not the Control of the current cell.

Answer (score -1):

you can't apply indexing with[] to gridviewtype

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the question. It is possible?

Answer (score -1):

```
 try referring this link might it give some clue to you..
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214505/2240266